# How to create HTML select option from JSON hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple JSON code:

```
[{'1':'Name'}, {'2', 'Age'}, {'3','Gender'}]
```

I have a select tag in my HTML:

```
<select name="datas" id="datas"></select>
```

I need a simple way to create HTML select box from this JSON, like this:

```
<select name="datas" id="datas">
    <option value="1">Name</option>
    <option value="2">Age</option>
    <option value="3">Gender</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Some tips: `foreach()`, `document.createElement()`, and `.appendChild()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for kicks here is an answer in pure javascript, also you probably do not need an array for this just a simple object will suffice

```
    <select name="datas" id="datas"></select>
    <script>

        html = "";
        obj = {
            "1" : "Name",
            "2": "Age",
            "3" : "Gender"
        }
        for(var key in obj) {
            html += "<option value=" + key  + ">" +obj[key] + "</option>"
        }
        document.getElementById("datas").innerHTML = html;

    </script>
```

Comment: `key` and `obj[key]` should at least be properly encoded. Imagine if `obj = {"1" : "> one &","2":"This has a quote \" in it"}`. It is safer to generate it using .append than joining html strings

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
//Correct(missing colons) in the array items
var data = [{'1':'Name'}, {'2': 'Age'}, {'3': 'Gender'}];
```

Create `option` element and then use `append` method to append them into select element.

```
var $select = $('#datas');
$.each(data, function(i, val){
    $select.append($('<option />', { value: (i+1), text: val[i+1] }));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MuGj7/)**

Answer (score 1):

The above answer assumes that the data indexes of the array are in order. What if the data variable would be:

```
var data = [ {'23':'Age'}, {'12':'Gender'}, {'3':'Name'}];
```

So in alphabetical order, but with random id's.

One way I found in solving this is:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  var i = Object.keys(value)[0];
  $("select#datas").append( $("<option />").val(i).text(value[i]) );
```