# How can I dynamically generate HTML dom using jQuery base on JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

## HTML

I have an accordion. Click on **" View Report "** will expand.

[image]

---

## JSON

I also have a [.json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/3as9e) file that contain 4 objects.

```
{

    "A": {

        "report_type": "chapter test",
        "section_num": "2",
        "assignment": "algebra 1",
        "date": "2/10/2015",
        "correct_num": "15",
        "avg_score": "89"
      
    },

    "B": {

        "report_type": "section exercise",
        "section_num": "2.2",
        "assignment": "algebra 1",
        "date": "2/09/2015",
        "correct_num": "11",
        "avg_score": "44"
        
    },

    "C": {

        "report_type": "test",
        "section_num": "1",
        "assignment": "algebra 1",
        "date": "1/10/2015",
        "correct_num": "15",
        "avg_score": "75"
       
    },

    "D": {

        "report_type": "practice test",
        "section_num": "1",
        "assignment": "algebra 1",
        "date": "1/09/2015",
        "correct_num": "15",
        "avg_score": "79"
       
    }
}
```

My goal is to **generate an accordion for each object I have** in my json file - so 4 in my case.

Then, set their text fields base on the data in my json file accordingly.

Any hints / suggestions on that will be much appreciated !

How can I dynamically generate HTML dom using jQuery base on JSON data ?

---

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/ymh22q7w/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: If you want a simple solution, check out a template library like underscore/lo-dash or jquery.tmpl. These will let you write a HTML template and pass your JSON into it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create HTML select option from JSON hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071525/how-to-create-html-select-option-from-json-hash)