# Cannot read JSON data using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have data in this format:

```
[{"data":{"maximum_seconds":"-1","emergency_address_code":"","e999_code":""},{"data":{"maximum_seconds":"-1","emergency_address_code":"","e999_code":""}}]
```

I am trying to read using JQuery.

I have tried multiple options, but none seem to be working.

```
for(var i in data) {
    console.log( data.maximum_seconds);
    console.log( data[i].maximum_seconds);
}

console.log( x[1].maximum_seconds);
```

my code is as follows:

var x = voip_get_numbers('', '');
var x = voip_get_numbers('', '');
x.done(function(data) {
    $('#d').append(data);

```
for(var i in jsonObjData) {
    console.log( data[i] );
}
```

});

any my JQuery function is:

```
function voip_get_numbers(account_seq, customer) {
    return $.ajax({
        url : '/section/voip/numbers',
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            "action": "list_numbers",
            "seq": account_seq,
            "customer": customer,
        },
        datatype: 'json',
    });
}
```

I did try some others, but my code has been overwritten so i don't have it - i think its a fairly simple task but i'm not the best with JQuery and JS so excuse my ignorance.

Any help would be great, please.

Thank you

Comment: There is no jQuery in this code.

Comment: your JSON is invalid

Comment: Yep, invalid json-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [As you can read this JSON using jquery or javaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255029/as-you-can-read-this-json-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery evident as already specified by CertainPerformance.

However, your JSON isn't properly structured. Should look like this.

```
 [
        {
            "data": {
                "maximum_seconds": "-1",
                "emergency_address_code": "",
                "e999_code": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "maximum_seconds": "-1",
                "emergency_address_code": "",
                "e999_code": ""
            }
        }
    ]
```

Example:

```
var a = [{
    "data": {
        "maximum_seconds": "-1",
        "emergency_address_code": "",
        "e999_code": ""
    }
}, {
    "data": {
        "maximum_seconds": "-1",
        "emergency_address_code": "",
        "e999_code": ""
    }
}]

//Syntax 1
for (var i in a) {
    console.log(a[i].data.maximum_seconds);
    console.log(a[i].data.emergency_address_code);
    console.log(a[i].data.e999_code);
}

//Syntax 2
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i].data.maximum_seconds);
    console.log(a[i].data.emergency_address_code);
    console.log(a[i].data.e999_code);
}

//Syntax 3
a.forEach( x => {
    console.log(x.data.maximum_seconds);
    console.log(x.data.emergency_address_code);
    console.log(x.data.e999_code); 
} );
```

And then why are you repeating the "data" property. You could do this:

```
 [
        {
            "maximum_seconds": "-1",
            "emergency_address_code": "",
            "e999_code": ""
        },
        {
            "maximum_seconds": "-1",
            "emergency_address_code": "",
            "e999_code": ""
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `JSON` data is `JSON` object and not a string.
If your data is a string, then convert it to `JSON` object.

jQuery provides this method: `$.parseJSON( jsonString )`

**Example:**

```
var data = '[{"data":{"maximum_seconds":"-1","emergency_address_code":"","e999_code":""},{"data":{"maximum_seconds":"-1","emergency_address_code":"","e999_code":""}}]';

var jsonObjData = $.parseJSON( data );
```

Comment: i've add all my code to my post - if i parseJSON, how would I read the data?

Comment: since your outer data is array, so you could probably read this with alert(jsonObjData[0].data.mazimum_sources) sorry i'm outside now so i can't test it.. i'll post working example later as soon as i back home.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is invalid. Change your file like this:

```
 [{
    "data": {
        "maximum_seconds": "-1",
        "emergency_address_code": "",
        "e999_code": ""
    }
}, {

    "data": {
        "maximum_seconds": "-1",
        "emergency_address_code": "",
        "e999_code": ""
    }
}]
```

I used [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate the file.

than you can parse the string to an object with

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

to get data from the object, use

```
for (var j in json) {
    var maximum_seconds = j.data.maximum_seconds
    var emergency_address_code = j.data. emergency_address_code
    var e999_code = j.data. e999_code
    // ... your code
}
```

Comment: i am using `json_encode($ret);` in PHP to create it.  the I have a function that returns an `$.ajax` call