# How to create HTML select option from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jquery-ui

I have a JSON file

```
{
    "1990": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    "1991": [ 4, 5, 6 ]
    // and so on...
};
```

I have a HTML file I have loop through it because a have large amount of data.

```
<select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="1990">1</option>
    <option value="1990">2</option>
    <option value="1990">3</option>
    <option value="1991">4</option>
    <option value="1991">5</option>
</select>
```

I have tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071525/how-to-create-html-select-option-from-json-hash) but it does not work for this does any suggest me how to solve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/MuGj7/

Thanks in advance and welcome suggestions.

Comment: I have another select option i has value 1990 and it should link to this year. both are link together. when a person select 1990 from another option it should link this value

Comment: Mr Rory McCrossan I working on the project which look like this  so i am trying one by one . Thanks for your time http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate the object and append an option element for each iteration:

```js
var obj = {
    "1990": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    "1991": [ 4, 5, 6 ]  
};

for (var i in obj) {
  for (var y in obj[i]) {
    $('#year').append($('<option value="' + i + '" data-value="' + i + '">' + obj[i][y] + '</option>'));
  }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="year" id="year"><select>
```

Comment: Can we add extra data-value to it which is looping. according to 1990. like this <option value='1990' data-value='1'>1</option> <option value='1990' data-value='2'>2</option>  <option value='1990' data-value='3'>3</option>. This table is linking to another table related to each other.

Comment: Just add any attribute when you create the element (Check my updated answer)

Comment: I am working on a project which look like http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/. but <option value='1990' data-value='1'>1</option> <option value='1990' data-value='2'>2</option> <option value='1990' data-value='3'>3</option> which is an array. it should count from array only.                                 if array contain 20 it should loop through. value should be 1990 and data-value=1 and so on.

Comment: i Think we have count the array and loop through it.